# How to concatenate a byte array into an existing one inside a Database

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq-to-sql

I have some LinqToSQL objects. 
One of those has a 'Binary' column, I think it's VarBinary(max) on SQL.

Every now and then I need to add/concatenate a byte array into that column for a certain row. This is how I do it:

```
void StoreBytesInDb(IEnumerable<byte> bytesToStore)
    {
        using (var dataBaseContext = new MyDataClasses(DatabaseInfo.ConnectionString))
        {
            if (this.currentObjectId == -1)
            {
                this.NewObjectToDatabase();
                this.currentSavedBytes = new List<byte>();
            }

            this.CurrentObject = dataBaseContext.Objects.Single(e => e.Id_Object == this.currentObjectId);

            this.currentSavedBytes.AddRange(bytesToStore);
            this.CurrentObject.Bytes_Data = this.currentSavedBytes.ToArray();

            dataBaseContext.SubmitChanges();
        }
    }
```

So, as you can see:

1. I use Linq to "AddRange" into the saved bytes (in the heap).
2. Then I put it into the right column in the object.
3. Submit Changes.

At low speeds it works.

The problem appears when I speed it up to several times per second. 
**Sometimes** it throws a 'System.ArgumentException' saying: "An item with the same key has already been added."
The exact line that throws the exception is:

```
this.CurrentObject.Bytes_Data = currentSavedBytes.ToArray();
```

Any tips on how to improve this?

Comment: If it's larger byte data you're dealing with - maybe move it out of Db , keep a ref onto File System - and append there - which is better. On the other note it may throw because of that 'NewObjectToDatabase' (if you save there too), that's just a guess.

Comment: @NSGaga thanks, that was definitely and improvement :) I changed it; but the same problem still persists. I don't think it throws beacuse I save the object in NewObjectToDatabase, I mean: the line that throws up is when I try to write in Bytes_Data (inside the object), and why does it do it only sometimes?

Comment: I put up an answer so you could vote etc. (since it helped fix a better 1/2 of it at least - the rest is easier). On the other part - could you post your model, and what's the pk etc. - it may be related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

None of this is optimal.

1. You should not store big files in the database
2. Linq 2 Sql is not optimized to do it
3. Also, it~s not a good idea to handle files all at once in memory - they might be big and you get and OOM exception

I would suggest you to:

1. Save the files somewhere else like @NSGaga said in his comment
2. If you must save in the database at least use a [FileStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/gg471497.aspx) column (which is pretty much saving into the database disk).
3. Do it like explained in [this article](http://blog.tallan.com/2011/08/22/using-sqlfilestream-with-c-to-access-sql-server-filestream-data/) so you are able to append to the file

Answer (score 1):

> If it's larger byte data you're dealing with - maybe move it out of Db
>   , keep a ref onto File System - and append there - which is better.

On the other thing - just an idea...

`currentSavedBytes` - why you keep that as a member? may be a concurency issue (if sharing) - try moving that in the scope of the method.

Comment: `currentSavedBytes` - why you keep that as a member? may be the `List` problem - try moving that in the scope of the method.